# Marklogic 8 DB backup issue

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am getting following error message.
Please let me know what I need to change , I have tried with other 2-3 location as well but facing the same error:

> Error: XDMP-BACKPUBLICDIR: Cannot backup to a forest's public data
>   directory/subdirectories : /data/

Answer (score 4):

This error indicates that you've attempted to back up a forest to the same directory it lives in. This is generally a bad idea because a disk problem that causes a loss of your forest would also cause a loss of your backup.

From the error message, I suspect your forest "data directory" is either "/" or "/data". If it's the latter, then some other directory such as "/backup" would work. Everything under "/data" would be rejected.

If it's the former ("/") then every directory on your machine would be disallowed. I would typically treat this case as a configuration error, although you would still be able to back up to "s3:" or "hdfs:" locations.

If you really want your backup to live in the same directory as your forest, then you can use "/some/dir/data" for your forest directory, and "/some/dir/backup" as your backup directory.

Comment: Thanks , i tried some different directory and worked fine.

Comment: @user7006501 since Wayne answered your question, please mark his answer as "Accepted".